# Why does List<T> blow up when i index into it?

Tags: c#

I created a list as a class level field like this:

```
private readonly IList<int> _intCol = new List<int>();
```

I then index into it and it blows up with the exception below:

```
_intCol[0] = 0;
```

**Exception:**

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.Parameter name: index

Comment: You haven't added anything yet. So, index 0 doesn't exist yet.

Comment: The size of your collection is zero, and your index is zero.  Zero is not less than zero, hence the error message.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question.  Why the downvotes?

Comment: @jfar: There is 1 downvote, and people can downvote for whatever reason they want to. Please don't clutter up the comment area with useless comments like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this point, `_intCol` is a list of the size 0, it does not have an element on the first position.

You can use `_intCol.Add(0);`.

See also:

- [`List<T>.Add(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx)
- [`List<T>.Insert(int, T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx)

If you do want to insert elements that way, you can use a `Dictionary<int,int>`, but note that your elements are not ordered - you just map numbers to numbers. For example:

```
Dictionary<int, int> integers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
integers[0] = 13;
integers[42] = 14;
```

`integers` now has two items, in no particular order:

```
{42: 14, 0: 13}
```

Comment: why type should i used that allows indexing like this?

Comment: @JamesRedcoat - see my edit. It depends greatly on what you need, though. For example, you cloud initialize an array if you know the size your collection will have, or want empty (0) elements between gaps. There are many considerations here...

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't populated the list with any elements, then trying to reference element 0 will fail just like that. You should check the Count first, and not reference any element index greater than Count-1.